# Is it possible to compare tables from different SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have to compare the tables in Server1 database A dbo.X and Server2, database B dbo.Y. Both table X and table Y contains same values.

SO I need to validate both tables contains same values in every row and column. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible.

Comment: `select ... from A full outer join B on B.primary_key = A.primary_key where A.primary_key is null or B.primary_key is null or A.not_null_column <> B.not_null_column or coalesce(A.null_column, '!@#$%^') <> coalesce(B.null_column, '!@#$%^') ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use any Tool like SSIS/Visual Studio then Linked Server will be required.

```
Select * FROM Server1.databaseA.dbo.X
EXCEPT
Select * FROM Server2.databaseB.dbo.Y
```

EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t output by the right input query.

[EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188055.aspx)

Comment: so lets say if my server1 is 1.0.0.1 and server2 is 1.0.3.4 then

`Select * From 1.0.0.1.A.dbo.X`
`EXCEPT`
`Select * From 1.0.3.4.B.dbo.Y`

Is that the right way?

Comment: Yes, If your linked servers are setup. You have to run both way `X EXECEPT Y` and `Y EXCEPT X`. If both return 0 records, the table contains same records.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it by creating linked servers. Please, follow this manual to create it:
[Creating Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

After this you will able to make sql-queries to another server like this:

```
SELECT name FROM [SRVR002\ACCTG].master.sys.databases ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more easy way if you have visual studio installed. There is a option to compare schema and data with any server and it is very efficient as you can update the target server within the tool as well.

VisualStudio -> Tools -> SQL server -> Data Comparison